# Clojure's partition-by in PHP?

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, functional-programming

coming from an FP background and now learning PHP I'm naturally missing some beloved higher-order functions. I was wondering if there's anything like Clojure's `partition-by` in PHP. Here's the official description of what it does:

> `(partition-by f)(partition-by f coll)`
>
> Applies `f` [a function] to each value in `coll`, splitting it each time `f`
>   returns a  new value.  Returns a lazy seq of partitions.  Returns a
>   stateful  transducer when no collection is provided.

I don't really care about the lazy and transducer parts (which I guess are out of the question in PHP anyway, am I right?) What I need to do is tranform an array like this :

```
[["year" => 2019, "val" => "foo"],
 ["year" => 2019, "val" => "bar"],
 ["year" => 2020, "val" => "baz"],
 ["year" => 2020, "val" => "boo)"]]
```

into this:

```
[[["year" => 2019, "val" => "foo"],
  ["year" => 2019, "val" => "bar"]],
 [["year" => 2020, "val" => "baz"],
  ["year" => 2020, "val" => "boo)"]]]
```

i.e. I want to group them by the result of a function like this:

```
function getYear($pair)
{
    return $pair["year"];
}
```

I haven't tried yet to code something like this up myself, but I was wondering if anything like this exists in a functional lib (or even the core?) of PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does not exist as a language feature. However, there are ready classes that do the same. Example:

```
$f = [
 ["year" => 2020, "val" => "baz"],
 ["year" => 2019, "val" => "foo"],
 ["year" => 2019, "val" => "bar"],
 ["year" => 2020, "val" => "boo)"]
];

//https://github.com/jspit-de/tableArray
$newArr = tableArray::create($f)
  ->orderBy('year ASC,val ASC')
  ->fetchGroup(['year'])
;

//test output
echo '<pre>';
var_dump($newArr);
```

Output:

```
array(2) {
  [2019]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    array(2) {
      ["year"]=>
      int(2019)
      ["val"]=>
      string(3) "foo"
    }
    [1]=>
    array(2) {
      ["year"]=>
      int(2019)
      ["val"]=>
      string(3) "bar"
    }
  }
  [2020]=>
  array(2) {
    [2]=>
    array(2) {
      ["year"]=>
      int(2020)
      ["val"]=>
      string(4) "boo)"
    }
    [3]=>
    array(2) {
      ["year"]=>
      int(2020)
      ["val"]=>
      string(3) "baz"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks… that does work for all intents and purposes!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this exists as a language feature. At least I haven't or couldn't find anything.

However, (unless I misunderstood) this should give you the result you described, with the caveat that the initial array must first be sorted by the partition value:

```
$f = [
 ["year" => 2019, "val" => "foo"],
 ["year" => 2019, "val" => "bar"],
 ["year" => 2020, "val" => "baz"],
 ["year" => 2020, "val" => "boo)"]
];

var_dump(partitionMultidim($f, "year"));

function partitionMultidim(array $values, string $key):array{
    $new = [];
    $p = $values[0][$key]; // alternatively check if exists in loop and set if not
    $partitionNum = 0;
    foreach($values as $value){
        // what is the current value?
        $curPartitionVal = $value[$key]; // or getYear($b);
        // has the value changed?
        if ( $p !== $curPartitionVal ){
            // set the next partition value
            $p = $curPartitionVal;
            // new partition index
            $partitionNum++;
        }
        // add to the new array
        $new[$partitionNum][] = $value;
    }   
    return $new;
}
```

Comment: Hi, I can only mark one answer as the solution. Yours did work for me but jspits gave me some insights into less known classes…

Comment: It does give insight into the class the answerer created! It is neat, but adds a dependency; one that is not tracked by something like composer at that.